# onTouch event problem

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

In my activity, I have a ScrollView with an OnTouchListener.
This scrollView contains some imageViews.

The problem is that when I touch an imageView, the onTouch(view,event) function of the OnTouchListener is called, but the view parameter is the scrollView instead of the imageView. Is it normal?
How can I have the real touched view in parameter?

edit:

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.affichagefiche_scrollview);
touchListener = new OnTouchScrollListener("---");
scroll.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
private class OnTouchScrollListener implements OnTouchListener{
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("activity", "onTouch: "+view.toString());
    }
}
```

The logs tells me that the view in parameters is always the scrollView, not a child

Comment: can you update your code

Answer (score 0):

try bind OnTouchListener to imageViews or do it by getX,getY coords

Comment: I tried to extends imageView to have a custom imageView and to override the onTouch(event) method but the scrollViewOnTouchListener is always called before.

actually, as the view on parameter of the scrollviewOnTouchListener is always the scroll view and not a child, I iterate over my imageViews array to test if I touched an imageView with the Region.contains(x,y) method. But when I'm scrolling down, the getX() and get(Y) of the event always give me the x and y on the screen, not the real x and y in the scroll view :/

Answer (score 0):

it will be more easier if you use setOnItemClickListener to get individual imageView of ScrollView.Then use onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id).

Comment: that works only if I am in a listView with an adapter, which is not the case here

Comment: This line says that "scroll.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);" you setOnTouchListener in scrollView,not in child.So if you have limited number of imageView the use onClickLisener otherwise use gridView.you can use horizontal gridView or vertical gridView.

Comment: the problem is that I need the onTOuchListener in my scrollVIew to track finger movement's. If I use an ontouchListener on the scroll and an onClickListener on the imageViews, the click is not handled by the child and the ACTION_DOWN event neither.